# Why CoroutineExceptionHandler can only perform launch when the coroutineContext is MainScope()?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have the below code and purposely trigger an exception to be caught by `errorHandler`

```
    private var coroutineScope: CoroutineScope? = null
    private val mainThreadSurrogate = newSingleThreadContext("Test Main")

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(mainThreadSurrogate)
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        // reset main dispatcher to the original Main dispatcher       
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
        mainThreadSurrogate.close()
    }

    private val errorHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { context, error ->
        println("Launch Exception ${Thread.currentThread()}")
        coroutineScope?.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            println("Launch Exception Result ${Thread.currentThread()}")
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun testData() {
        runBlocking {
            coroutineScope = MainScope()
            coroutineScope?.launch(errorHandler) {
                println("Launch Fetch Started ${Thread.currentThread()}")
                throw IllegalStateException("error")
            }?.join()
        }
    }
```

This will result in

```
Launch Fetch Started Thread[Test Main @coroutine#2,5,main]
Launch Exception Thread[Test Main @coroutine#2,5,main]
Launch Exception Result Thread[Test Main @coroutine#3,5,main]
```

If I change `coroutineScope = MainScope()` to either

- `coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)`
- `coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)`

The `coroutineScope?.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {...}` will not run i.e. the `Launch Exception Result ...` will not get printed.

Why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, we need to create a Scope using `SupervisorJob()`, so that the parent job is not affected by the child job crash.

```
coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.IO)
```

Note the `MainScope()` is `CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.Main)`.

As mentioned in [`SupervisorJob`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-supervisor-job.html)

> A failure or cancellation of a child does not cause the supervisor job to fail and does not affect its other children, so a supervisor can implement a custom policy for handling failures of its children